# Can I use a Cat5e cable with an RJ45 and Cat6 port?

Tags: wired-networking

I want to have wired connection but my laptop has an RJ45 port and my wall port is a Cat6 and the only wire I have is a Cat5e.

I don't want to go out buying new cables and converters so I was wondering if all 3 are compatible.

Answer (score 15):

### Yes. This should work.

Let’s break down what you are describing.

- [RJ45](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#8P8C) is the modular connector on an Ethernet cable.
- [Cat6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_6_cable) and [Cat5e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable) are just designations for rated quality/speed of the cable. Cat6 provides “[…lower crosstalk, higher signal-to-noise ratio…](https://www.bittree.com/blogs/get-connected/difference-between-cat5e-and-cat6)” when compared to Cat5e other specs below that level.
- Cat6 is backwards compatible with Cat5e.

So when you say:

> “…my wall port is a Cat6…”

Cat6 is just the specification rating of the cabling. The wall port being somehow labeled “Cat6” could just mean that the small bits of wiring within the wall port itself adhere to Cat6 specifications.

But the RJ45 connector on that Cat6 wall port is the same for Cat6 and Cat5e and the spec for Cat6 is backwards compatible to Cat5e so it should all work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If the plugs fit, it will work.  And a few feet of Cat5e on the end of (probably) a far greater length of Cat6 won't affect performance.

What's a 'Cat6 port'?  Cat6 is a cable spec., not a connector type.

Comment: not exactly true - different jacks can be rated for cat5 or cat6.

Comment: Yes, I see the marketing.  Not sure how you'd downgrade a RJ45 connector to not handle Cat6 though...

Comment: Remember a wall port connector still has some small bits of writing in them. So—let’s say—you wanted to have Cat6 quality in and out (into the socket and out through the wiring behind the port) then if the port itself has some small bits of wiring that contribute to more interference and cross talk, then you get a bottle-neck with that wall port.

Comment: @LaurencePayne The jacks and plugs are backwards compatible between CAT5 and 6, however the backside of the jack (where you punch the wires down) and the RJ45 plugs (the clear part that goes inside the jack) are *not compatible* between CAT 5 and 6. The wires are different diameters. So to the user they are compatible but not to an installer.

Answer (score -1):

It works, just remember, while technically Cat 5E can run up to 1Gbps under ideal conditions, it isn't *rated* for 1Gbps (it was a theoretical bandwidth when the standard was introduced). Cat 6 is designed for 1Gbps.

Comment: It sounds like you're suggesting that Cat5E isn't guaranteed to run 1Gbps, it just happens to do so most of the time. Can you provide a citation to back this up?

Comment: Also, the original poster just wanted to know if they could use Cat5e cables with  Cat6 ports. It definitely can be done. And the connection seems to be short: Laptop to the wall. So I don’t see a speed issue at all unless that is one gnarly Ethernet cable.

Comment: cat 5e runs gigabit fine, and even 10Gbe under the right conditions, so this seems... incorrect